# Sinch app Crash when Call Hangup method in background ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch

I am using Sinch SDK for App To App audio/video calling. Below is the scenario in which my application is crash. I implement Interactive local notification to Answer and Decline from lock screen for incoming call.

- User A Call User B. User B's application is in the background state.
- User B drag notification and click on decline button.
- On button click event call [call hangup] method.
- when i call that method my application is crash with reason 'error: memory read failed for 0x0'.
- But when i call answer method then nothing will happen.

Please suggest me, How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message and code snippet that produces it?

Comment: Are you launcing the app and then asnwering? Apple wont let you start a AVSession to record if the app is in hte background

Comment: Yes, On answer button tap, I am launching the app. And show them call accept denied button. But When user decline at that time I did not launch application simply call **[call hangup]** method in the background. When I call **[call answer]** instead of **[call hangup]** method then the application is not crash.